# Override gives me an error I cant find the function

Tags: flutter, dart

*Use `;` instead of `{}` for empty constructor bodies.dart(empty_constructor_bodies)
A function body must be provided.
Try adding a function body.dart(missing_function_body)*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final int questionIndex;
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  Quiz(this.questionIndex,this.questions,this.answerQuestion)

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
                children: [
                  Question(
                    questions[questionIndex]['questionText'],
                  ),
                  ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>)
                      .map((answer) {
                    return Answer(answerQuestion, answer);
                  }).toList()
                ],
              );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Searched for the error and damn, I had made the same silly mistake!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need to add a `;` at the end of the constructor:

```
Quiz(this.questionIndex,this.questions,this.answerQuestion);
```

Comment: I bet you worked with kotlin for some time before writing that constructor :)